# Sumar 4 columnas de 4 tablas diferentes

Tags: sql

estoy haciendo un sistema de inventarios en el cual debo de generar una tabla con una vista llamada Inventario general el cual debe sumar los valores de cuatro bodegas existentes. En la base de datos tengo las cuatro tablas de las cuales solo debo sumar la cantidad de piezas que hay por producto de cada una de las tablas y mostrar el total en inventario general. Pero aun no logro conseguirlo.

```
$xcrud = Xcrud::get_instance();
$xcrud->table('inventario_general');
    $xcrud->relation('id_producto', 'producto', 'id_producto', 'nombre_producto');
    $xcrud->relation('id_categoria', 'categoria', 'id_categoria', 'nombre_categoria');
     $xcrud->subselect('cantidad_piezastj','SELECT cantidad_piezas FROM inventario_real WHERE id_producto = {id_producto}');
     $xcrud->subselect('cantidad_piezascb','SELECT cantidad_piezas FROM inventario_cabos WHERE id_producto = {id_producto}');
     $xcrud->subselect('cantidad_piezassd','SELECT cantidad_piezas FROM inventario_sd WHERE id_producto = {id_producto}');
     $xcrud->subselect('cantidad_piezasmx','SELECT cantidad_piezas FROM inventario_mxl WHERE id_producto = {id_producto}');
        $xcrud->subselect('precio_compra','SELECT precio_compra FROM inventario_real  WHERE id_producto = {id_producto}');
            $xcrud->subselect('total_vendido','{total_piezas}*{precio_compra}'); 
           // $xcrud->subselect('total_piezas','{cantidad_piezasmx} + {cantidad_piezastj} + {cantidad_piezascb} {cantidad_piezassd}');
            //$xcrud->subselect('total_piezass','{cantidad_piezascb} + {cantidad_piezassd} ');
           $xcrud->subselect('total_piezas', 'SELECT SUM(cantidad_piezas) FROM (SELECT sum(cantidad_piezas) cantidad_piezas FROM inventario_real UNION ALL SELECT sum(cantidad_piezas) FROM inventario_mxl UNION ALL SELECT sum(cantidad_piezas) FROM inventario_cabos  WHERE id_producto={id_producto}');
```

Las tablas son:

- `bodegaA`: las columnas son `id_producto`, `cantidad_piezasa`, `preciocompra`, `totaldinero`,
- `bodegaB`: las columnas son `id_producto`, `cantidad_piezasa`, `preciocompra`, `totaldinero`,
- `bodegaC`: las columnas son `id_producto`, `cantidad_piezasa`, `preciocompra`, `totaldinero`,
- `bodegaD`: las columnas son `id_producto`, `cantidad_piezasa`, `preciocompra`, `totaldinero`.

De las cuales tengo que sumar la `cantida_piezas` de los productos que hay en cada tabla y ponerlo en un inventario general

Comment: ¿Cómo es la estructura de tablas? ¿Qué cosas has intentado?

Comment: las tablas son:  -bodegaA las columnas son id_producto, cantidad_piezasa, preciocompra, totaldinero  -bodegaB las columnas son id_producto, cantidad_piezasa, preciocompra, totaldinero   -bodegaC las columnas son id_producto, cantidad_piezasa, preciocompra, totaldinero -bodegaD las columnas son id_producto, cantidad_piezasa, preciocompra, totaldinero. de las cuales tengo que sumar la cantida_piezas de los productos que hay en cada tabla y ponerlo en un inventario general

Comment: ¿Y cuando tengas otra bodega más vas a agregar otra tabla? ¿Por qué no tienes una sola tabla con un quinto campo, que tenga el nombre de la bodega (o el Id si tienes una tabla de Bodegas...)? Ahí la consulta queda simplemente `select id_producto, sum(cantidad_piezas) from ProductosBodegas group by id_producto`

Comment: Las bodegas estan separadas porque cada una tiene sus propias entradas y salidas y sus propias ventas, cada bodega necesita manejar su propio inventario. Es por esta razon que cada una es una tabla. Pero ya he podido lograr lo que buscaba, de igual manera Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

para esto se usa Union all

```
Select Sum(cantidad) cantidad_total from (
select sum(cantidad) cantidad from tabla 1
union all
select sum(cantidad) from tabla 2
union all 
select sum(cantidad) from tabla 3) as Total
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero no me ha funcionado.

Comment: Podrías agregar a tu pregunta lo que intentaste y como debería quedar el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

para iniciar creo que la BD está mal diseñada, no debería tener sino una tabla por sino lo ha notado las cuatro tablas tienen los mismos campos, por otro lado debería usar un procedimiento almacenado(no sé que gestor de BD está usando para poner ejemplo), dicho procedimiento q devuelva todos productos con sus totales y de que bodega son o todos los productos sin importar bodega.
Espero haber ayudado, buen día. Y la consulta quedaría algo así

```
SELECT SUM(cantidad),
Producto, bodega
FROM OrderDetails group by producto,bodega;
```

Comment: por favor revisa [answer] no solo es texto si no también código y convendría añadas algo en código de lo que indicas